# Retrofit2 and JacksonConverterFactory error with Adapter

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm developing an application that uses Retrofit2 to upload some photos to a server, this is my code:

```
    public static class NetworkClient {
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://myServer/";
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Context context) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .build();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}

public interface UploadAPIs {
    @Multipart
    @POST("tools/index.php/testUpload/do_upload")
    Call<SimpleAdapter> uploadAttachment(@Part MultipartBody.Part filePart);
}
```

but when I try I get the following error:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class android.widget.SimpleAdapter]: can not instantiate from JSON object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)
>        at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@a0717cf; line: 1, column: 2]

Comment: did you get a solution? I realised I am am to get it working adding .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()) but without that, I get a whole bunch of errors.